# Exchange 2013: shared mailbox very large

Tags: outlook, exchange-2013

I have an Exchange 2013 server with a dozen users.
These users are using a shared mailbox for sharing all communications in nearly a thousand subfolders for a total of about 20GB.
Unfortunately, the automatic synchronization of Outlook folders is not working and to get the updated display must press on "Update Folder" or restart outlook

What can I do to improve the situation?
Should I switch to a "public folder"?

Comment: Exchange 2013 supports mailboxes up to 100GB, so 20GB doesn't sound that large to me. I really  only have 1 suggestion: Don't use cached mode.